# Why does MariaDB raise a syntax error even if running the code manually it works?

Tags: sql, docker, mariadb

I have a Dockerfile which copies all files from a directory into the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory. All files init perfectly except following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE filterRentalStationByString (
    IN str VARCHAR(255),
    IN cnt INT
)
BEGIN

    SELECT
        r.id,
        r.rental_station_name,
        r.language_id,
        r.address,
        a.street,
        a.city,
        a.house_number,
        a.zip_code

    FROM
        rental_stations r
        INNER JOIN addresses a ON r.address = a.id

    WHERE
        MATCH( zip_code, city, street, house_number ) AGAINST ( str )
        OR
        LOWER( CONCAT( rental_station_name, street, city, house_number, zip_code ) ) LIKE LOWER( CONCAT( '%', str, '%' ) )

    LIMIT
        cnt;

END
```

When I run the code from Intellij everything works fine but when I try to start and setup the database with docker-compose I receive this error message:

`db-mariadb-1  | 2022-10-22 08:13:02+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/03_stored_procedure.sql`

`db-mariadb-1  | ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 13`

Comment: Does IntelliJ actually run an instance of MariaDB or MySQL to validate or verify SQL or does it have a general SQL syntax checker but cannot be configured to match the feature-set of a specific MariaDB/MySQL version?

Comment: Maybe a `DELIMITER` is missing, see [MariaDB :: Delimiters](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/delimiters/).

Comment: Also... what version are you running?

Comment: There's no point having a `LIMIT` cause in your query without an `ORDER BY`, because otherwise the order of resultset rows is _undefined_.

Comment: Solved the problem, a DELIMITER was missing

Answer (score 1):

Solved this question, I added a DELIMITER before the create statement.